# NullPointerException with pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that .show() indicates that everything is normal but .toPandas(), .count(), .write.parquet("abc/abc_pred.parquet") all result in NullPointerException.  I cannot do anything with this dataframe.  Any ideas how I can export this dataframe?

Comment: Please show us the whole error message and add some more information. How did you create the dataframe? Did you apply transformations or aggregations? Please show us a printSchema().

Answer (score 0):

For your ref to create the data frame

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
data = [(1, "siva", 100), (2, "siva2", 200),(3, "siva3", 300),(4, "siva4", 400),(5, "siva5", 500)]
schema = ['id', 'name', 'sallary']

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show()
+---+-----+-------+
| id| name|sallary|
+---+-----+-------+
|  1| siva|    100|
|  2|siva2|    200|
|  3|siva3|    300|
|  4|siva4|    400|
|  5|siva5|    500|
+---+-----+-------+


df.agg({"sallary": "max"}).withColumnRenamed('max(sallary)', 'max').show()
+---+
|max|
+---+
|500|
+---+
```

Comment: This doesn't answer to the problem and infarct the problem is not cleared yet.